# R In install.packages("RGtk2") : fatal error: 'gdk/gdkx.h' file not found

Tags: r

when I install.packages("RGtk2") in R this I get this problem:

```
    fatal error: 'gdk/gdkx.h' file not found
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Rgtk.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RGtk2’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/RGtk2’
* restoring previous ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/RGtk2’
```

I install GTK using brew in macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Answer (score 3):

According to the [INSTALL documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RGtk2/INSTALL), you have to have Gtk libraries installed first:

> In all cases (i.e. Unix or Windows, source or binary), you will need
>   to have the appropriate Gtk libraries.
>
> For Windows, you can download the GTK Developer's Pack
>   from http://gladewin32.sourceforge.net/
>
> For Unix, you can fetch the source files for the different
>   libraries from
>      ftp://ftp.gtk.org/pub/gtk/v2.8/
>
> GTK makes extensive use of other libraries
>   and particular versions of these dependant libraries.  As a result,
>   installing GTK (under Unix) can be a time consuming and apparently indirect
>   process that involves installing numerous sub-libraries.

I suspect HomeBrew's Gtk might not be installed on your system properly.

Further research reveals [similar problems, as well as suggested troubleshooting](https://gist.github.com/sebkopf/9405675) to get Gtk and `RGtk2` to work together.

Answer (score 0):

The installation of **RGtk2** can be much easier now. First install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), then in R:

```
system('brew install gtk+')
install.packages(
  'RGtk2', type = 'mac.binary.el-capitan', repos = 'https://macos.rbind.org'
)
```

If you do not prefer using the repository https://macos.rbind.org (which was created by me) to install the pre-built binary package, you may just install **RGtk2** from source:

```
system('brew install gtk+')
install.packages('RGtk2', type = 'source')
```

In case anyone is curious about the technical details, the error "'gdk/gdkx.h' file not found" has been fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/lawremi/RGtk2/commit/cfe87505172b813850ecda371a00a92f6caac88c) in the **RGtk2** repo on Github.